# Add event listeners to shapes in android.graphics package

Tags: android

I am new to android programming & I'm trying to create a simple program where I can handle drag & touch events on different shapes.

From the android API, I understand that it is easy to add event listeners to widgets(eg:ImageView). But how do I do the same for graphics such as RectF or Circle?

Since I'm a novice, I would appreciate if someone could explain in simpler terms.

Comment: How is your situation setup? Are you using using a custom view where you are overriding the ondraw method? Please post some code so others can get a better understanding of your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things like [OnClickListeners](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) can only be added to subsets of the [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) class.

However, for shapes etc. you can override the onTouch() method for your base layout. Then in [MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_DOWN) you get the coordinates of the touch point, and see if they intersect with any of your shapes. If it intersects with a shape, then the user clicked that shape, and you can implement whatever code you need to.

Comment: An enhancement to this is to create classes to represent the shapes you want to draw.  Include a draw() method which takes a Canvas as an argument.  Also include your x and y co-ordinates (or Rects) where the shape will draw.  In the onDraw() method of the parent view, call the draw method of each drawing class passing the canvas of the view.  Now add a method to the new classes such as wasTouched(x,y). In the onTouch events, call the wasTouched() method of each drawing class to see if it was touched then do whatever you need to.

Answer (score 0):

You can override onTouch method of your View

Whenever there is a touch, get the coordinate of the touch

Use Rect.contains(x,y) to detect whether the touch is inside a specific Rect

Perform action accordingly